# About sketching a graph of functions by using matlab

Tags: calculus

My question is that by using matlab program, can you sketch the graph of the following functions $(1-s)^{\beta}$ and $1-s^{\beta}$, where $1\leq \beta\leq  2$ and $0\leq s\leq 1$. 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Here are the sketches using $MATLAB$ $R2017b$:[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But i could not access the website you added.

Comment: Your welcome. This is the only standard way to upload an image, but if your problem still persists, I suggest you trying another browser or use a VPN software....